# hyphenation not working

Tags: hyphenation

I really searched a lot and tried a lot of hints (also from this site), but I cannot get the global hyphenation command working.

In my text, I can set the correct hyphernation like this:

```
LensKit"=Frame"-work
```

but if I try to set it globally it's not working:

```
\hyphenation{LensKit-Frame-work}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a small example of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,ngerman]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{bibgerm}

\hyphenation{LensKit-Frame-work}

\clubpenalty = 10000
% Keine einzelnen Zeilen am Ende eines Abschnitts (Hurenkinder)
\widowpenalty = 10000 \displaywidowpenalty = 10000
% EOF

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   LensKit"=Frame\-work LensKit"=Frame\-work LensKit"=Frame\-work LensKit"=Frame\-work LensKit"=Frame\-work  LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework LensKit-Framework 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of problems.

1. You're not loading `babel`, so the `ngerman` option doesn't do anything. Actually the `bibgerm` package loads the obsolete `german` package.
2. Your `\hyphenation` instruction refers to the word "LensKitFramework" *without* explicit hyphens. TeX never hyphenates a word with an explicit hyphen, unless the user authorizes it to do, for instance with the `"-` shorthand.
3. The packages `ae` and `aecompl` are obsolete.
4. The instruction `\clubpenalty = 10000` *doesn't do what you're expecting.

Of course points 3. and 4. are not connected with the problem at hand, which you can solve by defining a macro:

```
\newcommand\LensKitFramework{LensKit"-Framework}
\hyphenation{frame-work}
```

Let's see the complete preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{bibgerm}


\hyphenation{frame-work}


\clubpenalty = 10000
\makeatletter
\@clubpenalty = 10000 % LaTeX uses `\@clubpenalty to restore the value of `\clubpenalty`
\makeatother
% Keine einzelnen Zeilen am Ende eines Abschnitts (Hurenkinder)
\widowpenalty = 10000 \displaywidowpenalty = 10000
% EOF

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\LensKitFramework}{LensKit-""Framework}

Here we use \LensKitFramework{} and it will hyphenate correctly.
```

The definition should go after `\begin{document}`, because it's only then that shorthands are activated.

Comment: Thanks to all these hints. I'm using a template for my diploma thesis. Seems it's a bit outdated :D

Comment: @egreg Does it really matter where you put `\newcommand`? I thought it's excecuted at the place of usage, not definition...

Comment: @tohecz The problem of putting it into the preamble is that there the category code of `"` is 12, not 13.

Comment: Oh ok, I forgot that they get changed only afterwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The following solution may be of relevance for people who don't use `babel` and hence can't use the methods proposed in the answers provided by @egreg and @DavidCarlisle.

Because the word "LensKit-Framework" already contains one explicit hyphen, TeX will not hyphenate the second (or, for that matter, the first) part of the long word. You can override this behavior either by writing

```
LensKit-\hspace{0pt}Framework
```

whenever this word crops up (TeX knows how to hyphenate `Framework`) or, more efficiently, define a macro such as

```
\newcommand{\LKF}{LensKit-\hspace{0pt}Frame\-work}
```

in the document's preamble and then use `\LKF` in the body of the document itself. With this setup, TeX will now break the word at the end of the line either after "LensKit-" or after "Frame".

Of course, if you wanted to let TeX choose a line break after "Lens" as well, you'd change the macro to

```
\newcommand{\LKF}{Lens\-Kit-\hspace{0pt}Frame\-work}
```

Answer (score 6):

TeX does not automatically hyphenate explicitly hyphenated words. Your command

```
\hyphenation{LensKit-Frame-work}
```

tells TeX two possible optional hyphenation points in `LensKitFramework` but your document does not have that it has `LensKit-Framework`. In a word with explicit hyphen TeX *only* considers the explicit hyphen as a possible break point. (The `babel` `"-` shorthand essentially makes the construct look like two words to TeX so it does consider each part of the compound separately.)

It is possible to set the lccode of `-` (so the hyphenation algorithm considers it part of a word), but as the standard hyphenation tables don't include this "letter" it would have to be done with care and generally I think most people recommend using the explicit `"-` construct or other explicit markup .